# Can spring cloud config server client listening new updates events ?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

Can spring cloud config server client listening new updates events? For example: new commit in git repository -> server sending event -> client notified & custom function called! **Thank you!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since git doesn't have events, you'll need to use your git server's webhooks. See http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Camden.SR6/#_push_notifications_and_spring_cloud_bus

On the config server add

```
<parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>Camden.SR6</version>
  <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-monitor</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bus-amdp</artifactId>
    <!-- -amqp (rabbitmq) or -kafka -->
  </dependency>
<!-- ... -->
</dependencies>
```

Then you need to add a webhook to your config server `http://<configserverurl>/monitor`

On config client add

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bus-amqp</artifactId>
  <!-- -amqp (rabbitmq) or -kafka -->
</dependency>
```

More details here https://spencergibb.netlify.com/blog/2015/09/24/spring-cloud-config-push-notifications/

Comment: To second what @spencergibb mentioned, I have also blogged about this: http://tech.asimio.net/2017/02/02/Refreshable-Configuration-using-Spring-Cloud-Config-Server-Spring-Cloud-Bus-RabbitMQ-and-Git.html